# outputPanel not rerendered

Tags: rerender, outputpanel

does someone has an idea, why the outputpanel "timeline" is not rerendered?

```
<apex:inputCheckbox id="budget" value="{!opp.Budget_available__c}" />
<apex:actionSupport event="onclick" rerender="pr, timeline" action="{!countPr}"/>
<apex:outputLabel for="budget" value="Customer has definded budget" />
<apex:outputPanel id="timeline">
<apex:outputPanel style="margin-left:3px;" rendered="{!IF(opp.Budget_available__c, 'true', 'false')}">
           Timeline: <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Timeline__c}" />
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the expression `IF(opp.Budget_available__c, 'true', 'false')` could be replaced with the simpler `opp.Budget_available__c` either will work.

Presumably `opp.Budget_available__c` is false initially. Are you assuming that when the budget checkbox is changed that the timeline label will render? That will only happen if you add:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox id="budget" value="{!opp.Budget_available__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="timeline"/>
</apex:inputCheckbox>
```

More explanation in [Rendering section if checkbox is unchecked](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18529/rendering-section-if-checkbox-is-unchecked).

Comment: when I changed the event on "onchange", it works. Thanks!
I am wondering why it works with onchange but not with onclick

Comment: @Provider That's good. I had always assumed you would also need to nest the apex:actionSupport inside the apex:inputCheckbox too; probably safer to make that change too.

Comment: I think this is not necessary in this case. The same usage but for the outputText component is shown on the component reference page :)